# Map SQL with JOIN, GROUP BY, and SUM to Entity Framework query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

I'd like to map the following SQL to EF query. I found a few similar topics, but still failed to achieve the mapping. {0}...{2} are SQL parameters.

```
SELECT TaskGroup.Project AS Project
SUM(Datediff(minute, WorkLog.StartTime, WorkLog.EndTime)) / 60 AS Hours
FROM WorkLog INNER JOIN TaskDefinition ON WorkLog.TaskDefinitionID = TaskDefinition.ID
INNER JOIN TaskGroup ON TaskDefinition.TaskGroupID = TaskGroup.ID
WHERE WorkLog.EmployeeID = {0} AND WorkLog.Status = 5 AND
   WorkLog.StartTime >= {1} AND WorkLog.EndTime < {2}
GROUP BY TaskGroup.Project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
var query = (from wl in WorkLog
            join td in TaskDefinition on wl.TaskDefinitionID equals td.ID
            join tg in TaskGroup on td.TaskGroupID equals tg.ID
            where wl.EmployeeID == { 0} && wl.Status == 5 
                && wl.StartTime >= { 1} && wl.EndTime < { 2}
            select new
            {
                Project = tg.Project,
                StartTime = wl.StartTime,
                EndTime = wl.EndTime
            })
            .GroupBy(o => o.Project)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Project = g.Key,
                Hours = g.Sum(o => (o.EndTime - o.StartTime).Minutes) / 60
            });
```

Comment: I will mark this as resolved but note the following: GROUP BY won't be executed on the DB server but instead performed localy. That means that all the relevant data rows have to be retrieved from the server, which, for a large table, is a huge performance loss. It seems that .NET Core 2 isn't able to create an efficient GROUP BY query yet.

Comment: Are you sure? I've just tested a similar query (joins, select, group by and select) and using `context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(s);` I've noticed that only one query is executed in SQL Server and this query is executing the group by (I'm not using EF Core, I'm using EF 6.1.3 in .Net Framework 4.6.1)

Comment: Yes, with EF core, if you set local grouping to throw an exception (instead of warning), it does happen.